# How to enforce select a value in selection option using simple_form on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How could I enforce user to choose a service_type,

because when the page loaded, the select option shows "choose one?" by default

```
-service_type=[a,b,c]
= f.input :service_type, label: "service", collection: @service_type, prompt: "choose one?"
```

Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by setting the model attribute to the value you want to enforce before rendering the input:

```
- f.object.service_type = your_default_service_type
= f.input :service_type, label: "service"....
```

I'd recommend you to do it on the model or the controller other than in the view.